# Can't fetch links connected to different exhibitors from a webpage

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I've been trying to fetch the links connected to different exhibitors from ***[this webpage](https://www.topdrawer.co.uk/exhibitors?page=1)*** using python script but I get nothing as result, no error either. The class name `m-exhibitors-list__items__item__name__link` I've used within my script is available in the page source so they are not generated dynamically.

> What change should I bring about within my script to get the links?

This is what I've tried with:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

link = 'https://www.topdrawer.co.uk/exhibitors?page=1'

with requests.Session() as s: 
    s.headers['User-Agent']='Mozilla/5.0'  
    response = s.get(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text,"lxml")
    for item in soup.select("a.m-exhibitors-list__items__item__name__link"):
        print(item.get("href"))
```

One such links I'm after (the first one):

```
https://www.topdrawer.co.uk/exhibitors/alessi-1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Life is complex is right that site you used to scrape is protected by [Incapsula service](https://www.incapsula.com/) to protect site from web scraping and other attacks, it checks for request header whether it is from browser or from robot(you or bot), However it is more likely site has proprietary data, or they might preventing from other threats

However there is option to achieve what you want using Selenium and BS4
following is code snip for your reference

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import requests

link = 'https://www.topdrawer.co.uk/exhibitors?page=1'

CHROMEDRIVER_PATH ="C:\Users\XYZ\Downloads/Chromedriver.exe" 

wd = webdriver.Chrome(CHROMEDRIVER_PATH)

response = wd.get(link)

html_page = wd.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page,"lxml")
results = soup.findAll("a", {"class" : "m-exhibitors-list__items__item__name__link"})

#interate list of anchor tags to get href attribute
for item in results:
    print(item.get("href"))
wd.quit()
```

Comment: I should have thought of selenium as an option in the first place. I intentionally avoided that only because when i found out that the content are static. Thanks for your solution @Dev.

Answer (score 1):

The site that you are attempting to scrape is protected with Incapsula.

```
target_url = 'https://www.topdrawer.co.uk/exhibitors?page=1'

response = requests.get(target_url, 
headers=http_headers, allow_redirects=True, verify=True, timeout=30)
raw_html = response.text
soupParser = BeautifulSoup(raw_html, 'lxml')

pprint (soupParser.text)

**OUTPUTS**
soupParser = BeautifulSoup(raw_html, 'html')
('Request unsuccessful. Incapsula incident ID: '
'438002260604590346-1456586369751453219')
```

Read through this: https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-scrape-content-with-Python-from-a-website-protected-by-Incapsula

and these: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Incapsula